# PHP: HTML Attribute Encoding / JavaScript Decoding

Tags: php, javascript, html, xss, html-entities

What's the proper way to encode untrusted data for HTML attribute context?  For example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data; ?>" />
```

I usually use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to do this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($data); ?>" />
```

However, I recently ran into an issue where this was breaking my application when the data I needed to pass was a URL which needed to be handed off to JavaScript to change the page location:

```
<input id="foo" type="hidden" value="foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2" />
<script>
    // ...
    window.location = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    // ...
</script>
```

In this case, `foo` is a C program, and it doesn't understand the encoded characters in the URL and segfaults.

I can simply grab the value in JavaScript and do something like `value.replace('&amp;', '&')`, but that seems kludgy, and only works for ampersands.

So, my question is: is there a better way to go about the encoding or decoding of data that gets injected into HTML attributes?

I have read all of [OWASP's XSS Prevention Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), and it sounds to me like as long as I'm careful to quote my attributes, then the only character I need to encode is the quote itself (`"`) - in which case, I could use something like `str_replace('"', '&quot;', ...)` - but, I'm not sure if I'm understanding it properly.

Comment: Doesn't urlencode take care of that in PHP? There is few code examples in comments that show how to protect against XSS too on the php manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @gillesc: `urlencode()` is for encoding URL *parameters*, not whole URLs, and does not encode for the HTML attribute context.  There is a section in the manual that even talks about this - *"Leave it as &, but simply encode your URLs using htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars()."*

Comment: are you sure about `window.location = document.getElementById('foo');`? that should be like this I think-> `window.location = document.getElementById('foo').value;` and it redirects to right page(foo?bar=1&baz=2)

Comment: @ocanal: Thank you, I've corrected that, but this does not address the problem, because it will redirect to `foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2`.  PHP is able to understand this, but `foo` is not a PHP script, and just crashes unless the URL is like `foo?bar=1&baz=2`.

Comment: The actual `value` of the input in your case is `foo?bar=1&baz=2`, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqkn3/). Your script as posted won't result in a redirect to `foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2` but to `foo?bar=1&baz=2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current method of using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` is the right approach.

The example you provided is correct HTML:

```
<input id="foo" type="hidden" value="foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2" />
```

The ampersand in the value attribute does indeed need to be HTML encoded, otherwise your HTML is invalid. Most browsers would parse it correctly with an `&` in there, but that doesn't change the fact that it's invalid and you are correct to be encoding it.

Your problem lies not in the encoding of the value, which is good, but in the fact that you're using Javascript code that doesn't decode it properly.

In fact, I'm surprised at this, because your JS code is accessing the DOM, and the DOM should be returning the decoded values.

I wrote a JSfiddle to prove this to myself: http://jsfiddle.net/qRd4Z/

Running this, it gives me an alert box with the decoded value as I expected. Changing it to `console.log` also give the result I expect. So I'm not sure why you're getting different results? Perhaps you're using a different browser? It might be worth specifying which one you're testing with. Or perhaps you've double-encoded the entities by mistake? Can you confirm that's not the case?

Answer (score 5):

> What's the proper way to encode untrusted data for HTML attribute context?

If you add double quotes around the attribute value, htmlspecialchars() is enough.

> ```
>  <input id="foo" type="hidden" value="foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2" />
> ```

This is correct, and the browser will send `foo?bar=1&baz=2` (decoded `&amp;`) to the server. If the server isn't seeing `foo?bar=1&baz=2`, you must have encoded the value twice.

Getting the value in javascript should return `foo?bar=1&baz=2` too (e.g. `document.getElementById('foo').value` must return `foo?bar=1&baz=2`).

View the source of the page using your browser and see the actual source of the input field.

If you are modifying the input field's value using Javascript, then the script must be double-encoding it.

BTW your program shouldn't segfault because of wrong user input ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM to decode the value:

```
function decodeHTMLSpecialChars(input){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = input;
  return div.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : div.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

This will render the following string:

```
'http://someurl.com/foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2'
```

to this:

```
decodeHTMLSpecialChars('http://someurl.com/foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2');
// => 'http://someurl.com/foo?bar=1&baz=2
```

And no, for HTML encoding and decoding, the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and html escaping is the standard method and is doing the job just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the `html_entity_decode` function in PHPJS:

http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode

Other than that you could base64 encode your data instead...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using `htmlentities` as it is doesn't help!

By default it just encodes `" < > &`

It doesn't escape `'` which can create a problem!

Make sure you use Flags for the functions , you can find the usage and examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: Thank you, but this would only matter if you do not properly delimit your attribute values with `"` characters, and I do.  It's bad practice to leave out delimiters or delimit with `'`.